# addition of two multidimensional array of different sizes

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I am learning `Java` for a week now and this program gives me an error in `add` method. I can't find out why?

```
int a[][]= {{211,21,32,34},{20,21}};
int b[][]={{31,42},{45,21}};

public static void add(int x[][], int y[][]){
    int ar=0,al=0,i=0;

    if(x.length>=y.length) {
        ar=x.length;
    } else {
        ar=y.length;
    }
    if(x[i].length>=y[i].length) {
        al=x[i].length;
    } else {
        al=y[i].length;
    }
    int s[][] = new int[ar][al];
    for(i=0; i<ar; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<al; j++) {
            s[i][j]=x[i][j]+y[i][j];
        }
        for(i=0; i<ar; i++) {   
            for(int j=0; j<al; j++) {
                System.out.print(s[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, then?

Comment: upload your stacktrace

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: One of your arrays is bigger than the other one.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Did you read the title?

Comment: the variables `ar` and `al` are being initialized with the max(row of the arrays) and max(column of the array) now you tell me in this example the value of the al would be 4, how would you access fourth column of any row in second array, that why you are getting indexoutofbound..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
if(x.length>=y.length) //!!PROBLEM!!
{
    ar=x.length;
}
else{
    ar=y.length;
}
if(x[i].length>=y[i].length) //!!PROBLEM!!
{   al=x[i].length;

}
else{
    al=y[i].length;
}
```

You're taking the *larger* of the sizes between these two matrices, which means that whichever one is smaller will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` whenever you try to index the larger rows/columns.

The logic should be flipped; take the minimum of these lengths:

```
if(x.length <= y.length) //FIXED
{
    ar=x.length;
}
else{
    ar=y.length;
}
if(x[i].length <= y[i].length) //FIXED
{
    al=x[i].length;
}
else{
    al=y[i].length;
}
```